# Beginner here. Which arduino revision should i buy?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have no idea what difference is there between the revisions and how it affects me. I have a pdf and this pic was in there: 
[image: arduino pic]

My questions

- which arduino revision is this?
- Does it matter which revision i    buy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like an early-version Uno, rather than an Uno R3 as shown below. (Image is from dxcdn.com and is one of the first few images in a [google images for Uno R3](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1002&bih=626&q=UNO+R3&oq=UNO+R3&gs_l=img.12..0l7j0i5i30l3.1757.1757.0.2961.1.1.0.0.0.0.92.92.1.1.0.ecynfh...0...1..64.img..0.1.91.PlZ5WbbvIEA#imgrc=gYQV8pLWKcYuZM%3A) search.)

[image: Uno R3]

For a beginner, replacing a DIP ATMEGA328P may be a chip too far.  I suggest that rather than looking for an Uno with a replacable chip, get any Uno you like.

Also note that for beginning projects, it makes sense to use the same kind of Arduino – an Uno, a Mega, a Pro Mini, a Nano, etc. – as the guide you are following uses, so that you won't have to adapt any pin numbers and wiring pictures.  As you gain experience, it should become easy to adapt designs to different boards.

Comment: It looks very much like the R2 that I have here.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an UNO R2, the type with DIP micro controller (you can extract it and replace it with another one, in case of problems).
The R3 version is probably the best choice to get started.
You might want one that has a connector where this one has only the 3x2 empty pads on the top left (close to the vertical writing AREF).
Have a look on ebay/aliexpress/amazon. You can find it for as little as $5-$6. Just search for UNOR3, if you elect to buy this type.

Comment: Looks more like an R2 to me.

Comment: Whoops, true, it's R2, I'll fix it. But I still think the removable AVR is better than the SMD one.